# C++ and String Concatenation Vulnerabilities

Tags: c++, security, string-concatenation

I'm new to C++ and currently working on a simple program shown below that concatenates two strings input by a user. I was learning about the different methods of concatenating, and saw many tutorials using "+" to add the two strings together. I was also reading about possible vulnerabilities with strings in C++, and was wondering if it is technically safer to use something like the "append()" function? What possible vulnerabilities do both options present? Thank you in advance for any advice you may offer for a beginner!

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
   string str1, str2;

   cout << "Enter a string: ";
   getline(cin, str1);

   cout <<"Enter a second string: ";
   getline(cin, str2);

   str1.append(str2);

   cout<< "Strings concatenated: " << str1;

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: _"...possible vulnerabilities with strings..."_ please give details as it's hard to answer your question when we don't know what your concerns are.

Comment: No safer. Both make sure sufficient storage exists before trying to write into it. Wouldn't be overly surprised if the implementation had one function calling the other.

Comment: Note: You are probably being confused by [C-style null terminated strings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string). Many, many things can vex the unwary with C-style strings. In C++ they should only be used when rare circumstances force it. The C++ `std::string` class avoids many of the problems of the C-Style string if used correctly.

Comment: Which vulnerabilities are you referring to? That were there in C style functions like `strcat` (to which Microsoft had developed their safer versions). But in C++ `std::string`s no such thing happen. The class itself checks out for all potential errors and throws respective exception in case something is likely to go wrong / goes wrong.

Comment: My course was asking to provide an analysis of potential vulnerabilities that could be taken advantage of in our program. I was getting a little confused throughout some of my readings when both C, and C++ examples were being used. I was getting confused mainly whether this program could in any way lead to a buffer overflow in some way. I know that I have not set parameters for the length of the strings to be entered so is that a potential risk? I'm on information overload at the moment from reading so many sources so I apologize if I'm spouting nonsense >.<"

Comment: `std::string`, used properly, will size itself to fit or throw an exception if it can't get enough memory to size itself. If you use it wrong, you can still go flying off the end and shoot yourself in the foot a few dozen ways, but appending two `string`s is about as safe as you can get.